# upgrading sql query join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
   SELECT e.id AS event_id, e.title, e.date, e.category, e.place,
          p.id, p.name, p.coor, p.nz,
          a.user, a.event, COUNT(a.user) AS attending
     FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN attendance a
       ON a.event = e.id
LEFT JOIN places p
       ON p.id = e.place
 GROUP BY e.id, e.title
 ORDER BY attending DESC
```

this query get events from events table, and join some other tables... (if you can help me to make it more efficent i would thank you)

I have another table called: invited_friends:

```
event_id    bigint(20)    
user_id int(11)   
owner   tinyint(1)
```

it stores the user ids that invited for a certien event .. (owner is bool that store if the user is the creator of the event)

**I want to select only if the current user is invited based on the data in invited_friends table.**

Comment: INNER JOIN, it worked but not all my events has invited users, some of them are public to everyone... so it will ignore them: `code`INNER JOIN invited_friends i ON (
i.event_id = e.id
)
AND (
i.user_id =1439375286
)`code`

Comment: How do you know what events are public? Where is that stored?

Comment: if e.category = 4, then it is a private event, when im using inner join like i showed it just ignore every event beside the ones that have invited friends.

Comment: I've modified my answer below to cater for the category. If the category is not equal to 4 then I'm assuming it is public and should be included, otherwise make sure the @username has been invited

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with MySql but here goes:

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id, e.title, e.date, e.category, e.place,
      p.id, p.name, p.coor, p.nz,
      a.user, a.event, COUNT(a.user) AS 
FROM 
    events AS e
    LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.event = e.id
    LEFT JOIN places p ON p.id = e.place
WHERE 
    e.Category <> 4 
OR  EXISTS (SELECT
                NULL
            FROM
                invited_friends
            WHERE
                invited_friends.event_id = e.id
            AND invited_friends.user_id = @username -- User to search for
            )
GROUP BY 
    e.id,
    e.title
ORDER BY 
    attending DESC
```